# When I log in: what username must I use

Tags: support

I'm having trouble logging in, primarily because I am usually automatically logged in.

If I must log in it always fails.  What username should I use?  There are three possibilities in my simple mind:
1) The name I wish to be displayed:  GeofAndron
2) My email address which I used when setting up the account which is:   xxxxxxx
3) A numerical userid which as assigned to me when I first created an account and which doesn't seem to go away.

Each time I log on manually, I have to ask for a login page be sent to my email address.  It's wasting bandwidth!

Sorry for this dumb question.

GeofAndron

Answer (score 5):

There is no login for any Stack Exchange site. You login to your *openID* provider such as [Gmail](http://gmail.com) (or Google Accounts), [Yahoo](http://mail.yahoo.com), [Facebook](https://facebook.com), [Stack Exchange](https://openid.stackexchange.com/), etc. and authorize each Stack Exchange site to use your credentials.

[image]

When you click "login" on a site, you're actually logging into your openID provider. So your *Mathematica* Stack Exchange username/display name/user number etc. don't play into any of this unless you also happened to choose the same  name for your openID.

---

I've checked your login options and it appears that you are using your email address for two different openID providers. You can see which ones they are by visiting [your profile](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1508/geofandron) and clicking on the "my logins" link. Your user name for both these providers will be your email address that you used and the password for that provider.